# How is CSS em measurement used for height or border-radius measured?

Tags: css, font-size

I understand that the "em" measurement is a relative unit for font-size, relative to the font-size of the containing element if it's specified in an absolute unit like px, or to the default font-size in the browser.

But I'm trying to understand how using em as a measurement for the border-radius of a box element, like a div, works. I'm assuming it's related to how using em as a measurement for the width or height of a box works.

Is it still related to font-size? How, specifically, is it measured? The explanations for how border-radius is computed that I've been able to find all seem to be based on px units.

Comment: It works similarly to `font-size`. `div { font-size: 20px; border-radius: 2em; }` equates to `border-radius: 40px`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding you question, but I think it works like this. If the font size is 12px and you make a box with a border radius of 1em, then it will have a border radius of 12px (13px if it's 13px). This is useful if you need the box's border radius to stay in the same ratio to the text regardless of the text's size. For instants, if you had a box with text in it, lets say:

```
<style>
  // lets say the browser gives the text a default size of 16px on a pc
  .box {border-radius:5px}// lets say the box's size scales with the text
</style>
```

It would look as though the box had almost completely round corners. But lets say on an iphone, it gives the text a default size of 80px (exaggeration) it would seem as though the box had virtually flat corners. The solution is to have the box's corners scale with the text using em.

Comment: Thanks all! I was looking for how it's computed. Sounds like the em is converted to px based on the font size, so in that way behaves similar to font-size (and using the same inheritance rules, etc.) So it is not relative to the width or height of the element, but rather the font-size the element would have (if one was specified or one was inherited from a parent).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it's related to font-size. In the end it's still a unit of measurement, like px.

This **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/YegmH/4/)** might give you a better idea on how it works.

**Markup:**

```
<div id="A"></div>
<div id="B"></div>
<div id="text-height"></div>
<p>Some text</p>

<div id="C"></div>
<div id="D"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
p {
    line-height: 1em;
    background: grey;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
}
#A {
    height: 4em;
    background: red;
    width: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
}
#B {
    height: 2em;
    background: blue;
    width: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
}
#text-height {
    height: 1em;
    background: green;
    width: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
}
#C, #D {
    height: 4em;
    width: 4em;
    display: inline-block;
}
#C {
    border-radius: 2em;
    background: red;
}
#D {
    border-radius: 1em;
    background: blue;
}
```

**Image:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried this in the browser and [it is still relative to the font-size property of the element](http://jsfiddle.net/RecTM/). If the font-size is not defined, it inherits from the next parent that has a font-size, or the browser defaults ([which is 16px usually](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss/); TIL).