# I can't get my border-radius hover effect to appear wider

Tags: css, hover

I'm trying to apply a border-radius hover effect to navigation links, but I can't seem to get it bigger than this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/COZ5z.jpg). Here's a snippet of my code:

CSS:

```
.nav a:hover {
    background: #091D6C;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 1em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">

   <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

</ul>
```

If anybody could help, that'd be awesome. This is for my school project that's due this week. Thanks!

Here's the CSS of my navigation:

```
.globalheader .navigation li {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.globalheader .navigation .nav {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 1.2em;
    padding-right: 1.2em;
    height: 5.8em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navigation {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 4.8em;
    margin-bottom: 2.4em;
    border: .1em solid transparent;
}
```

Sorry for not being more clearer with my question and thank you for the quick replies!

Comment: What do you mean by "bigger"? You can add `padding:1em`, or something similar....

Comment: I'm not sure why your using ``em`` (ems) as the unit of measurement for the border radius. ``em`` is relative to the font size (as [explained in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092927/how-is-css-em-measurement-used-for-height-or-border-radius-measured)), you should be using something like ``px`` (pixels) or ``%`` (percentages) instead

Comment: Dude, please, learn how to ask questions. I see none in your “question”.

Comment: Could you post the CSS for all of the navigation. Or post a jsFiddle?

Comment: @ub3rst4r I usually use `em` units for `border-radius`. It keeps the look of the roundness consistent when/if the font size changes.

Comment: @showdev I wasn't asking you. Your not the one who posted this question, are you?

Comment: @ub3rst4r No need to be defensive. I'm offering an example of when `em` units might be useful, not attacking your personhood.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. This is my first time asking a question here, sorry.

We have to use ems because it's a school project and I don't know why our teachers makes us use ems uniquely for this project.

Answer (score 1):

border-radius has four values, for each radii are given in the order

1. top-left
2. top-right
3. bottom-right
4. bottom-left

If bottom-left is omitted it is the same as top-right. 
If bottom-right is omitted it is the same as top-left. 
If top-right is omitted it is the same as top-left.

It shortens the border of your text, so in order to make it bigger you can add `padding` value. I go with @showdev.

example

```
.nav a:hover {
    background: #091D6C;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 1em;
    padding: 16px; // or 1em;
}
```

you can also refer to w3school about border-radius -- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Comment: I did this however the text moves out of place. What could I do to make the text not move?

Comment: you can try this jsbin link -- http://jsbin.com/repegekide/1/edit?html,css,js,output

hope that answers your question.